# WHERE IN clause AS object Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

If I have a `Company` objects :

```
var companies = db.Companies.Where(...);
```

And a `User` objects which related to `Company` object `one-to-many` :

```
var users = db.Users.Where(...);
```

How I can achieve a criteria like `select * from users where user.company in (company)`

Reading from some articles, I tried something like :

```
users.Where(x => companies.Contains(x.company))
```

But seems doesn't work. What I missed here?

**EDIT**

Exact Answer :

```
public PartialViewResult IndexGrid(String search)
{
    var companies = db.Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId()).Companies.AsQueryable();
    Guid[] guids = companies.Select(c => c.Id).ToArray();

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
        return PartialView("_IndexGrid", db.Set<Quotation>().OrderByDescending(x => x.Code).AsQueryable()
            .Where(x => guids.Contains(x.Company.Id)));
    else
        return PartialView("_IndexGrid", db.Set<Quotation>().OrderByDescending(x => x.Code).AsQueryable()
            .Where(x => guids.Contains(x.Company.Id))
            .Where(x => x.Code.Contains(search)|| x.MasterCustomer.Name.Contains(search)));
}
```

Comment: You forgot to tell what "doesn't work" with your attempt. If `companies` is EF6 `IQueryable`, then your attempt actually works. If it is in-memory `IEnumerable`, then both your attempt and current answers throw `NotSupportedException` at runtime.

Comment: @IvanStoev : the error actually come from other plugin https://github.com/NonFactors/MVC5.Grid saying kinda accept primitive value. There is no error thrown by controller it self but the grid didn't work. The accepted answer give me an idea to work with / I put an exact answer in question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use last variant as

```
users.Where(x => companies.Contains(x.company))
```

.Net doesn't know how to compare Companies and uses references to equal objects.
Please, try this if your Company has id property. If not, please let me know.

```
users.Where(x => companies.Select(c => c.Id).Contains(x.company.Id))
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to select for its IDs:

```
var companies = db.Companies.Where(...);
var myUsers = db.Users.Where(w=>companies.Select(x=>x.Id).Contains(w.CompanyId)).ToList();
```

if you have a reference between them both, then you can for example:

```
var myUsers = db.Users.Include(x=>x.Company)
                   .Where(w=>w.Company != null && w.Company.Name == "MyCompanyName")
                   .ToList();
```